# jQuery/CSS - How to style the first occurrence of an element inside of another element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's my problem.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p>First paragraph that needs to be yellow.</p>
    <p>Second paragraph that need not change. :) </p>
    <p>Third paragraph that need not change. :) </p>
</div>
```

If I use `#content p:first-child {color:yellow; }` it doesn't work because `p` isn't the first-child of `content`... `h1` is the first born.

How can I do this without touching the HTML code?

**Thank you!**

All the best,
Cris

Comment: Do you want jQuery (Javascript) or CSS?

Comment: any would do. I got the answer with jQuery and works great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the best way:

```
$('#content p:first').css('color', 'yellow');
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you all.

Answer (score 20):

a css3 solution

```
#content > p:first-of-type { color: yellow; }
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use also (CSS, jQuery) [`nth-of-type`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype):

```
#content p:nth-of-type(1) {color:yellow; }

$('#content p:nth-of-type(1)').css('color', 'yellow');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.first()` function (or `:first` selector) instead:

```
$('#content > p').first().css('color', 'yellow');
```

Comment: see @Naveed's more succinct answer - that one's faster though they both work.

Comment: really? ISTR reading that the function based filters are faster than using sizzle-based selectors because they require less parsing.

Comment: I think that is the official advice from jQuery, because Sizzle parses right-to-left, whereas jQuery parses left-to-right. Hence Sizzle will select every `p:first` and then narrow it to the `p:first` with a parent of `#content`, whereas jQuery will first select `#content` and then select the `p`s, and then select the first one. However, the performance is negligible in normal HTML pages.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged it using jQuery, jQuery based solution:

<del>$("#content p:first-child").css({color:"yellow;" });</del>

EDIT:

```
$("#content p:nth-child(2)").css({color:"yellow" });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#content p:first').css('color','yellow');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With just CSS, you could use the sibling selector `+` like so:

```
#content h1 + p { color: yellow; }
```

This would only change paragraphs immediately following H1s.

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work in some browsers.  Specifically those that begin with I and end with E

Comment: @Milimetric Ha, quite right. Though it has apparently worked non-dynamically since IE 7 (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Comment: In [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGCQe/) its making all of the p tags yellow not just the first one

Comment: @ExtraGravy Your example works correctly for me in Firefox 4.0.  What browser are you using?

Comment: @D Gauer I'm using Chrome.  I would have expected these two to work alike, is weird

Comment: @ExtraGravy Fascinating.  I get the same results you do in Chrome.  I would have expected the same results as well!

Comment: @ExtraGravy This appears to be a Chrome bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=74180  I'll have to think twice about using the sibling selector if even Chrome has this problem. :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#content p').first().css({ color: 'yellow' });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("div p:first")
        .css("text-decoration", "underline")
        .hover(function () {
              $(this).addClass("sogreen");
            }, function () {
              $(this).removeClass("sogreen");
            });
```